# Why does pandas boolean filtering result in floats?

Tags: python, pandas

New to pandas, so apologies if this has been asked before.

I have the following:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {
  'a': [1, 2, 3, 4],
  'b': [1, 2, 3, 4]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

# We want to remove values above 2.
cutoff = 2
boolean_filter = df < cutoff
new_df = df[boolean_filter].dropna()
print(new_df.head())
```

It's my understanding that pandas will coerce values if there's multiple types. As such, I thought the presence of `nan` was causing the numbers to be coerced to floats.

However, even after adding `.dropna()` the resulting DataFrame has floats.

Why is this, and how can I keep the values as ints?

Replit link [here](https://repl.it/repls/MiserableLimitedIrc).

Comment: You can fall back to numpy if you want to remove those elements and end up with a 1d structure: `df.values[boolean_filter]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`df[boolean_filter]` returns a dataframe containing `NaN` values:

```
print(df[boolean_filter])

     a    b
0  1.0  1.0
1  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN
```

This should be expected as you are indexing a dataframe with a Boolean 2-dimensional array. But `NaN` values are considered `float`, so Pandas must upcast all affected series to continue holding data in numeric series / arrays.

When you use `pd.DataFrame.dropna`, no "recalculation" of optimal data type is triggered. Therefore, your dataframe will now contain `float` values.

Instead, if you index via a 1-dimensional array, Pandas will convenient filter by row and you no longer need `dropna`:

```
print(df[boolean_filter.all(1)])

   a  b
0  1  1
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks!